# Zoom/scale from different point of image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, zooming, scale

I have made a canvas in html5. I'm using it to show parts of a bigger image that you can move and I want to make it possible to zoom both in and out. But I do not know how to make the image scale from a certain point. When I increase the size of the image the part which is shown by the canvas is moved, I want the part in the center of the canvas to be the focus point when the scaling is complete, but no matter how I try it gets distorted some how. It seems like depending on which part of the image is shown, when the scaling happens that part of the picture is going to get moved to different coordinates. I do not know what type of algorithm I would have to use so calculate the movement of the image.

This is a link to a visual example of the movement i mean, https://i.stack.imgur.com/66oWo.jpg, the two images are scaled the same but depending on which part of the image that is visible in the canvas, the amount the image needs to be moved tor the zoom differs.

This is my code, but it isn't really working that well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:50px;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="float:left;border:1px solid #000000;">Your browser doesn't support canvas</canvas>
        <div id="floorDown" onMouseDown="zoomIn()" style="width:200px;height:50px;float:left;">Zoom in</div><br>
        <div id="floorDown" onMouseDown="zoomOut()" style="width:200px;height:50px;float:left;">Zoom out</div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    //start position
    var imageX=0;
    var imageY=0;
    var imageWidth,imageHeight,imageRight,imageBottom;
    var draggingImage=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        imageWidth=img.width;
        imageHeight=img.height;
        draw();
    }

    img.src='http://orig00.deviantart.net/35cb/f/2013/030/f/0/tripolar_by_zy0rg-d5t9tqh.png';

    function draw(){
        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //Disable anti-aliasing
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled=false;
        // draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,imageX,imageY,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
        startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        draggingImage= true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
        draggingImage=false;
        draw();
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
        handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
        if(draggingImage){
            imageClick=false;
            mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
            mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
            // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
            var dx=mouseX-startX;
            var dy=mouseY-startY;
            imageX+=dx;
            imageY+=dy;
            // reset the startXY for next time
            startX=mouseX;
            startY=mouseY;
            // redraw the image with border
            draw();
        }
    }


    // TEST zoom in/out functions
    function zoomIn() {
        imageX=imageX*2;
        imageY=imageY*2;
        imageWidth=imageWidth*2;
        imageHeight=imageHeight*2;
        draw();
    }
    function zoomOut() {
        imageX=imageX/2;
        imageY=imageY/2;
        imageWidth=imageWidth/2;
        imageHeight=imageHeight/2;
        draw();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the origin (pos) and scale to zoom at a point

```
var pos = {x : 0, y : 0};
var scale = 1;
function zoomAt(x,y,_scale)
    scale *= _scale
    pos.x = x - (x - pos.x) * scale;
    pos.y = y - (y - pos.y) * scale;
}
```

You can then create the transform with

```
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, pos.x, pos.y);
```

So to zoom at the center of screen

```
zoomAt(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 1.1);  // zoom in
zoomAt(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 1 / 1.1);  // zoom out
```

Put all together

```js
// the following globals are available
// w, h, cw, ch,  width height centerWidth centerHeight of canvas
// canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime  
const image = new Image;
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/KTZ_2TE10U_Aynabulak.jpg/800px-KTZ_2TE10U_Aynabulak.jpg";

const font = {
    font : "28px Arial",
    textAlign : "center",
    textBaseline : "middle",
}

function setStyle(ctx, style){
    Object.keys(style).forEach(key => ctx[key] = style[key]);
}
// Handle all key input
const keys = {  // key input object
    ArrowLeft : false,  // only add key names you want to listen to
    ArrowRight : false,
    keyEvent (event) {
        if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {  // are we interested in this key
            keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
        }
    }
}
// add key listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", keys.keyEvent);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keys.keyEvent);


const view = (()=>{
    const matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current view transform
    const invMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current inverse view transform
    var m = matrix;  // alias
    var im = invMatrix; // alias
    var rotate = 0;  // current x axis direction in radians
    var scale = 1;   // current scale
    const pos = {      // current position of origin
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
    }
    var dirty = true;
    return {
        apply(ctx){
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            var m = matrix;
            ctx.setTransform(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3],m[4],m[5]);
        },
        update(){ // call to update transforms
            var xdx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
            var xdy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;
            m[0] = xdx;
            m[1] = xdy;
            m[2] = -xdy;
            m[3] = xdx;
            m[4] = pos.x;
            m[5] = pos.y;
            // calculate the inverse transformation
            cross = m[0] * m[3] - m[1] * m[2];
            im[0] =  m[3] / cross;
            im[1] = -m[1] / cross;
            im[2] = -m[2] / cross;
            im[3] =  m[0] / cross;
            dirty = false;
        },
        toWorld(x,y,point = {}){  // convert screen to world coords
            var xx, yy;
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            xx = x - matrix[4];     
            yy = y - matrix[5];     
            point.x =  xx * im[0] + yy * im[2]; 
            point.y = xx * im[1] + yy * im[3];
            return point;
        },        
        toScreen(x,y,point = {}){  // convert world coords to  coords
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            point.x =  x * m[0] + y * m[2] + m[4]; 
            point.y = x * m[1] + y * m[3] + m[5];
            return point;
        },        
        movePos(x,y){
            pos.x += x;
            pos.y += y;
            dirty = true;
        },
        setPos(x,y){
            pos.x = x;
            pos.y = y;
            dirty = true;
        },
        setScale(sc){
            scale = sc;
            dirty = true;
        },
        scaleScale(sc){
            scale *= sc;
            dirty = true;
        },
        scaleAt(x,y,sc){
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            scale *= sc;
            pos.x = x - (x - pos.x) * sc;
            pos.y = y - (y - pos.y) * sc;            
            dirty = true;
        }
    };
})();

function onResize(){
    setStyle(ctx,font);

}
const drag = {
    dragging : false,
    lastX : 0,
    lastY : 0,
    update(){
        var dx,dy;
        if(mouse.w){
            if(mouse.w < 0){
                mouse.w += 10;
                view.scaleAt(mouse.x,mouse.y,1/1.02);
                if(mouse.w > 0){
                    mouse.w = 0;
                }
            } else if(mouse.w > 0){
                mouse.w -= 10;
                view.scaleAt(mouse.x,mouse.y,1.02);
                if(mouse.w < 0){
                    mouse.w = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if(mouse.buttonRaw){
            if(!this.dragging){
                this.dragging = true;
                this.lastX = mouse.x;
                this.lastY = mouse.y;
            }else{
                if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
                    dx = mouse.x-this.lastX;
                    dy = mouse.y-this.lastY;
                    this.lastX = mouse.x;
                    this.lastY = mouse.y;
                    view.movePos(dx,dy);
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(this.dragging){
                this.dragging = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function display() { // call once per frame
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    if(keys.ArrowLeft ){ mouse.w += 10 }
    if(keys.ArrowRight){ mouse.w -= 10 }
    drag.update();
    if(image.complete){
        view.apply(ctx);
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillText("Click drag to pan. Wheel to zoom or left/right arrow.",cw,20)
    }else{
        ctx.fillText("Loading Image...",cw,ch)
    }
}




/******************************************************************************
 The code from here down is generic full page mouse and canvas boiler plate 
 code. As I do many examples which all require the same mouse and canvas 
 functionality I have created this code to keep a consistent interface. The
 Code may or may not be part of the answer.
 This code may or may not have ES6 only sections so will require a transpiler
 such as babel.js to run on legacy browsers.
 *****************************************************************************/
// V2.0 ES6 version for Stackoverflow and Groover QuickRun 
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime = 0;
// You can declare onResize (Note the capital R) as a callback that is also
// called once at start up. Warning on first call canvas may not be at full
// size. 
;(function(){
    const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
    var resizeTimeoutHandle;
    var firstRun = true;
    function createCanvas () {
        var c,cs;
        cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
        cs.position = "absolute";
        cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
        cs.zIndex = 10;
        document.body.appendChild(c);
        return c;
    }
    function resizeCanvas () {
        if (canvas === undefined) { canvas = createCanvas() }
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals() }
        if (typeof onResize === "function") {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutHandle);
            if (firstRun) { onResize() }
            else { resizeTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(onResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME) }
            firstRun = false;
        }
    }
    function setGlobals () {
        cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
    }
    mouse = (function () {
        function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault() }
        var m; // alias for mouse
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, // mouse position and wheel
            alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, // mouse modifiers 
            buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,                        // true if mouse over the element
            buttonOnMasks : [0b1, 0b10, 0b100],  // mouse button on masks
            buttonOffMasks : [0b110, 0b101, 0b011], // mouse button off masks
            active : false,
            bounds : null,
            eventNames : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(","),
            event(e) {
                var t = e.type;
                m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
                m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
                m.alt = e.altKey;
                m.shift = e.shiftKey;
                m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
                if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.buttonOnMasks[e.which - 1] }
                else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.buttonOffMasks[e.which - 1] }
                else if (t === "mouseout") { m.over = false }
                else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true }
                else if (t === "mousewheel") {
                    m.w = e.wheelDelta 
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { 
                    m.w = -e.detail 
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            start(element) {
                m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
                m.eventNames.forEach(name =>  document.addEventListener(name, mouse.event) );
                document.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
                m.active = true;
            },
        }
        m = mouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    function update(timer) { // Main update loop
        globalTime = timer;
        display();           // call demo code
        requestAnimationFrame(update)
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        canvas = createCanvas(); 
        mouse.start(canvas, true);
        resizeCanvas();
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    },0);
})();


/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

```css
#imageCC {
   font-family : arial;
   font-size : 10px;
   position : absolute;
   z-index : 100;
   bottom : 3px;
   right : 10px;
   background : rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id=imageCC>Image rights.
<a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Kabelleger">Kabelleger</a> / David Gubler (<a href="http://www.bahnbilder.ch">http://www.bahnbilder.ch</a>), <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KTZ_2TE10U_Aynabulak.jpg">KTZ 2TE10U Aynabulak</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode">CC BY-SA 3.0</a>
</div>
```